# No space between tabpanel and a form element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tabPanel where I put a form. There is no space between the tabPanel and the first element of the form. Is there a class in tbs to fix that?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#information" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#contactReference" data-toggle="tab">Référence</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>    

<div id='content' class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="information">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nom</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Entrer le nom" />
            </div>
          </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8262/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a custom class `top-margin`

**CSS**

```
.top-margin {
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal top-margin" role="form">
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/5h0gs4ny/)